# How to make the ImageView rounded in GridView of Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried to make the image rounded inside the Gridview but it appears as shown below. Please help me to solve this issue

[image]

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;

            if(convertView == null){
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                param.height = 300;
                param.width = 300;
                imageView.setLayoutParams(param);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                imageView.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
            }else{
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(image[position]);
            return imageView;
        }
```

The below is the shape.xml file that I have added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Background Color -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <!-- Border Color -->
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

    <!-- Round Corners -->
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library to do it easily and you will find examples in the read me or if you want to create your own version you can read the library code and learn from it to improve your own version

Answer (score 1):

I always use these two libraries for Round Image View

```
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
```

Example of circleimageview

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/textPrimary"
                app:civ_border_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textChangeBio" />
```

Example of RoundedImageView

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/photo1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
        app:riv_border_width="2dip"
        app:riv_border_color="#333333"
        app:riv_mutate_background="true"
        app:riv_tile_mode="repeat"
        app:riv_oval="true" />
```

you can also set custom radius in RoundImageView